Img-src doesnt resolve when url has more parameters after .../foo.png/
My URL: https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/valorant/images/9/9c/Raze_icon.png/revision/latest?cb=20230523180834
When opening this link in my browser, I see a raw picture. When referencing it in my <img src>, I dont get my image returned, but when I cut out everything after .png, it works.
Is there any other solution than string-splitting (because that doesnt seem like a clean solution), like changing headers, any library or so?
background-image: url(url) on a div also behaved the same as img-src. thx

Maybe you shouldn't be hot-linking to external sources (who then have to pay for the bandwidth to serve those images)?

Storing these images locally isnt possible here, because my project revolves around people being able to create TierLists, where they can insert image items including a url. any suggestions?

download the images from user supplied urls and then rehost them for your own site's use.  a lot of sites preemptively disallow hot linking (what you're running into), but even if you could it's really bad practice, not just because you're causing increased bandwidth for someone else, but the original host could also replace the image at that URL with something different, e.g. something incredibly offensive and/or NSFW and you presumably wouldn't want something like that suddenly on your site.

okay. still, do you have an idea why the image doesnt load? Would still be technically interesting.

@silj6
Hotlinking, also known as "inline linking" or "direct linking," occurs when someone embeds an image or other media from another website directly into their own site by using the URL of the original media file. This means that instead of hosting the image on their own server, they use the URL of an image hosted on someone else’s server.
Ref - https://blog.hubspot.com/website/hotlinking

The problem occurs because the image you're trying to fetch is hotlinked; the owner of the image does not want to share it. Please refer to my previous comment where I explain what hotlinking is.
BTW, Try this script with "spacial-images" class in your < img > tag
   <script>
      // Function to modify the image URLs
      function cleanImageUrls() {
        // Get all images with the class 'spacial-images'
        const images = document.querySelectorAll(".spacial-images");

        images.forEach((image) => {
          // Get the current src URL
          let src = image.src;

          // Use a regular expression to remove everything after .png or .jpg
          src = src.replace(/(\.png|\.jpg).*$/, "$1");

          // Set the cleaned URL back to the src attribute
          image.src = src;
        });
      }

      // Call the function to clean URLs
      cleanImageUrls();
    </script>

And For Vue JS
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- Image with cleaned URL -->
    <img :src="cleanedImageUrl" alt="Image" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      // Original image URL
      originalImageUrl: 'https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/valorant/images/9/9c/Raze_icon.png/revision/latest?cb=20230523180834'
    };
  },
  computed: {
    // Computed property to clean the URL
    cleanedImageUrl() {
      // Remove everything after .png or .jpg in the URL
      return this.originalImageUrl.replace(/(\.png|\.jpg).*$/, '$1');
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
/* Add any necessary styling here */
</style>

